# Application not opened in android

Tags: android, eclipse, java-me, lwuit

I developed the LWUIT based android application.
But that application could not opened in emulator.
I used eclipse 3.6.1 and android 2.2.
Can anyone tell me the proper steps for developing the LWUIT based android application?

Comment: Hi, can you put the log message?

Comment: [2010-11-12 11:30:17 - Phonebook] Installing Phonebook.apk...
[2010-11-12 11:31:14 - Phonebook] Success!
[2010-11-12 11:31:14 - Phonebook] Starting activity org.phonebook.ui.Phonebook on device emulator-5554
[2010-11-12 11:31:17 - Phonebook] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=org.phonebook.ui/.Phonebook }














































And in emulator i got the alert like "The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please Try again"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used LWUITActivity class for Android application. LWUIT framework having own activity class for developing Android application. For more info see this [link](http://www.pader-sync.com/lwuit-for-blackberry-and-android.html).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the LWUIT yet, but i think you may making mistake in attaching xml(interface layout) file inside the code file.

```
setContentView(R.layout.Phonebook);
```

It may helps, check it !!

Comment: see this link https://lwuit-incubator.dev.java.net/source/browse/lwuit-incubator/trunk/thorsten_s/android/README_Android.txt?rev=98&view=markup. Here they said how to build midlet on android and i followed the steps. I know i missed something while configuration. But I dont know what im missing? :(